# installing verbify-tts on ubuntu 23.04 need help

Tags: command-line, server, shortcut-keys, 23.04

Almost there! The last step is MANUAL.
The following two commands are needed to call the Verbify-TTS service.

- COMMAND 1: READ THE TEXT (recommended key combination: ALT + ESC)
  The following is to ask the service to read the selected text:
  /home/cameron/Downloads/Verbify-TTS-main/env/bin/python /home/cameron/Downloads/Verbify-TTS-main/command_read.py
- COMMAND 2: STOP READING (recommended key combination: ALT + END)
  The following is to stop the current reading:
  /home/cameron/Downloads/Verbify-TTS-main/env/bin/python /home/cameron/Downloads/Verbify-TTS-main/command_stop.py

what do i do to get this step done, setting up some sort of global shortcut to create files or something.